# Another Complicated Order By with Dates MS Access

Tags: sql, database, sorting, date, ms-access

I need help in creating a query to sort the column Hour from 9am to 8am (the next day).

I have union together 2 queries with separate order by and with date range parameters, and added rank to sort the returned rows. But it seems that the query return the rows of 9 to 23 query before returning the 0 to 8 query results. 
[unexpected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYtOU.jpg)

I have no idea on how to approach this as it is my first time to encounter this complex query. I have read a few threads about this and come up with this code.

```
SELECT StationCode, Month, Day, Year, Hour, Rainfall
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS rank, StationCode, Month, Day, Year, Hour, Rainfall, DateValue(CStr([Month] & '/' & [Day] & '/' & [Year])) AS [Date]
FROM table1
WHERE (((StationCode)=10) AND ((Hour)>=9) AND ((DateValue(CStr([Month] & '/' & [Day] & '/' & [Year]))) Between DateValue([month1] & '/' & [day1] & '/' & [year1]) And DateValue([month2] & '/' & [day2] & '/' & [year2])))
ORDER BY Month, Day, Year, Hour
UNION
SELECT 2 AS rank, StationCode, Month, Day, Year, Hour, Rainfall, DateValue(CStr([Month] & '/' & [Day] & '/' & [Year])) AS [Date]
FROM table1
WHERE (((StationCode)=10) AND ((Hour)<=8) AND ((DateValue(CStr([Month] & '/' & [Day] & '/' & [Year]))) Between DateValue([month1] & '/' & [day1] & '/' & [year1]) And DateValue([month2] & '/' & [day2] & '/' & [year2])))
ORDER BY Month, Day, Year, Hour) dt
ORDER BY rank, Month, Day, Year
```

Sample Data :

```
StationCode | Month | Day | Year | Hour | Rainfall
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    0 |       0 
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    1 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    2 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    3 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    4 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    5 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    6 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    7 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    8 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    9 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   10 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   11 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   12 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   13 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   14 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   15 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   16 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   17 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   18 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   19 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   20 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   21 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   22 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   23 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    0 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    1 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    2 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    3 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    4 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    5 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    6 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    7 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    8 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    9 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |   10 |       0
so on...
```

Expected Results:

```
StationCode | Month | Day | Year | Hour | Rainfall
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |    9 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   10 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   11 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   12 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   13 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   14 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   15 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   16 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   17 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   18 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   19 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   20 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   21 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   22 |       0
         10 |     1 |   1 | 2010 |   23 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    0 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    1 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    2 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    3 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    4 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    5 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    6 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    7 |       0
         10 |     1 |   2 | 2010 |    8 |       0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These question would be remarkably improved if it contained some *sample data* and *expected results*. You can run your query, all we have is a query that we cannot run (and we know is incorrect) and your narrative, which I'm struggling to follow.

Comment: Just change Order By clause (at last line) to Year, Month, Day, Hour, rank

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There I added sample data and expected results, sorry. This one is a really old database with records from 1969 up to present, but here i provided the records from January 2010 with 0 rainfall meaning there is no rain that day.

Comment: Other than cutting off the first 8 hours from the first day of your search range, and the last 16 hours from the last day of your search range, isn't order by year month day and hour sufficient? The fact that you consider the first 24 of those rows to be one "unit" (day) and the next 24 rows as the next "unit" seems irrelevant?

Comment: Hmm my search range is for the date only the hour is not included. I'm sorry but you have it reversed, the first day would have the 16hours (9 to 23) then the last day would have their first 8hours (0 to 8) to cover a full day of 9am to 8am. I'm trying to sort them as it is because I will use the query to display a matrix table in php using the `hour` for rows then `day` for columns. I first tried `usort` but I'm unsuccessful, so now I'm trying so sort within the query.

Comment: Your expected output is same as sample data except the hours 0-8 are missing. What are we missing?

Comment: Yes, they wanted to monitor the data for a whole day but instead of the normal time of 0 to 23hours it starts with 9am to 8am in the morning of the next day.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps you simply need to revise your where clause. If user chose `2010-01-01` and `2010-01-10` (10 days) you need to select rows between `2010-01-01 09:00` and `2010-01-11 08:00`, order by year, month, day and hour.

Comment: Oh wow, why i haven't thought about that. i think that will work thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Hour` column in the `order by` clause as well.
From what I have understand, rows 9 to 23 are in Hour column which will not be sorted as its not included int he `order by` clause.

Try this order: `Year, Month, Day, Hour`

Data will be sorted as 
    0-8 for day 1
    9-23 for day 1
    0-8 for day 2
    9-23 for day 2

Filter out data if you want for `day 1 and 0-8 hrs`, `day 2 and 9-23 hrs`

Also, `order by` clause in inner query won't make any difference since you are reordering it again in the outer query

Comment: Thank you but I tried that adding `Hour` column in the `order by` still returned the unexpected result as I linked in my post.

Comment: Try this order: Year, Month, Day, Hour

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the order-by clauses in the subqueries, they have no effect at all as the rows get sorted after the merge (union) anyway.

You have rank as the first sort criterion. Since you assign rank=1 in your first subquery, all these records appear first.

Try the following overall sort order: Year, Month, Day, rank, Hour

Update:

From your comment it seems you have a problem with the selection criteria, not the sort order.

Try this:

```
SELECT StationCode, Month, Day, Year, Hour, Rainfall
from table1
where StationCode=10
and DateAdd('h',-8,DateValue(CStr([Month] & '/' & [Day] & '/' & [Year]))
    Between DateValue([month1] & '/' & [day1] & '/' & [year1])
        And DateValue([month2] & '/' & [day2] & '/' & [year2])
order by StationCode, Year, Month, Day, Hour
```

The trick here is to shift the timestamp by 8 hours.

Comment: Oh, it did work. however, it only sorted 9 to 8 hours as per day not the way i intended it to be displayed as (9-23) to (0-8 of the next day).

Comment: PLease see my update. i haven't been able to test though, as I have no Access available.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, it wasn't working. I tried to fix the query, i tried adding column for `DateAdd` and it returned 1/1/2010 4:00 PM in every rows. I don't get it though I have no clue what you're trying to do maybe the query I made was far from your idea.

Comment: my basic idea was to substract 8 hrs from the timestamp before comparing it to the desired range ((date-8hrs) between date1 and date2). This excludes the first 8 hours from the range but includes the 8 hours following the range.